How to set soap version to 1.2 for a web service client using spring-ws-core?
My client is using org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:4.0.11, which internally relies on Jakarta XML Web Services (JAX-WS).
I need to generate a client proxy for a web service that supports both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 protocols. The proxy is generated via the wsimport Maven plugin from the WSDL. However, the auto-generated client is defaulting to SOAP 1.1, and I need it to use SOAP 1.2.
Current Implementation:
var service = new TargetWebService(); // Auto-generated from WSDL
var port = service.getPort(TargetWebServiceSoap.class);  
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, properties.url());

Internally, the binding is set to use SOAP 1.1, but I can't find a way to change it to SOAP 1.2 or modify how the Binding is created.
Question:
How can I configure the client to use SOAP 1.2 instead of SOAP 1.1?
What I Have Tried:

I have explored changing the binding properties, but I can't find documentation on how to explicitly switch the SOAP version.
The generated classes don't seem to provide any straightforward methods to configure the SOAP version.

Desired Outcome:
I need to force my client to use protocol version 1.2.

This question is similar to: Support both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 messages in Spring-WS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

One main difference is that, in this case, I can't use Spring boot.  That is pointed at the first paragraph. Spring core is not the same as spring boot, for instance, I can't use @Beans here.
